# How to share a filtered resource at generate-sources phase in a multi module project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, resource-files

I have a parent project with 3 child projects:

```
parent
   project-1
       /src/main/resources/config.xml
   project-2
       /src/main/resources/config.xml
   project-3
       /src/main/resources/config.xml
```

The configuration `config.xml` is used during the `generate-sources` phase. For the three projects, the `config.xml` is exactly the same. However, the usage of this `config.xml` is different for each project.

In project-X, I am referring to `config.xml` as following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>some-group</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>some-goal</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <input>src/main/resources/config.xml</input>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What is the best way to share this common `config.xml` between all 3 projects?

Comment: Opinion-based. There are too many answers and each one will have its own opinion. One possible way is to create a 4th module factoring the `config.xml`.

Comment: @Tunaki If we introduce a 4th module, how can we refer to that `src/main/resources/config.xml` from another pom?

Comment: I am afraid you can't refer to your 4th module from "configuration" section of the another pom.

Comment: As a solution I could suggest to move your config.xml to "parent" directory and refer to the file from child pom's using relative path, like "../configs/config.xml".

Comment: It is possible to refer from other modules via [maven-remote-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-remote-resources-plugin/) but the question is why do you need a resource like this in different modules which means it is on the classpath so define a single module which contains it and add the appropriate dependency to the modules which need it.. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise But I don't need it in the classpath. I need it during the `generate-sources` phase. I need to be able to refer to it in a `<configuration>` tag of a plugin.

Comment: @Tunaki A 4th module isn't needed here. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35366446/363573

Comment: @Stephan I didn't say it was the only solution. I said there were too many solution that would differ on opinions ;).

Comment: @Tunaki This leaves OP without solutions...

Comment: @Stephan I will try it out. Adding it to the parent project and propagating it with the `build-helper-maven-plugin` plugin seens a good solution. I will let you know and mark as resolved.

Comment: @SteveKelio The maven-remote-resources-plugin is exactly connected to the correct phase if not you can change it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` here.

> #### PROJECT STRUCTURE
>
> ```
> shared-resources-project
>   +-src
>      +-main
>         +-resources
>            `config.xml
>   +-project-A
>      `pom.xml
>   +-project-B
>      `pom.xml
>   +-project-C
>      `pom.xml
>   `pom.xml
> ```

---

#### `shared-resources-project/pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared-resources-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>project-A</module>
        <module>project-B</module>
        <module>project-C</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>${project.parent.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>config.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>some-group</groupId>
                <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>some-plugin-job</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>some-goal</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <input>${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.xml</input>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### `shared-resources-project/src/main/resources/config.xml`

```xml
<config>
    <parameter>${custom-value}</parameter>
</config>
```

#### `project-X/pom.xml`

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-resources-project</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project-X</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <custom-value>Project-X Value</custom-value>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Now, let's build the project:

```
D:\workspaces> cd shared-resources-project
D:\workspaces\java\shared-resources-project> mvn clean install
```

Some notes:

- The build-helper-maven-plugin will add the common `config.xml` file as a resource to Project-X.
- Then the Maven resources plugin (MRP) will copy `config.xml` to the project output directory (`target` directory by default). During the copy, MRP will also replace `${custom-value}` with the specific value provided by Project-X.
- The final `config.xml` will be available to another plugin as long as the other plugin is bound to the `generate-source` phase AND its declaration appears AFTER the `build-helper-maven-plugin` declaration. Maven (3.0.4+ at least) calls the plugins in their order of apparition in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: This does not really do want I want. In project-X, a build plugin is used which assumes that `src/main/resources/config.xml` exists. However, that plugin throws a `FileNotFoundException`. When is the `config.xml` from the parent copied to the project-X, and will it be accessible by another plugin?

Comment: I updated my question to clarify the usage of config.xml.

Comment: @SteveKelio You want to use `${project.build.outputDirectory}/config.xml` instead of `src/main/resources/config.xml`. See my notes and my edit in `shared-resources-project/pom.xml`. Note that in my anwser the build plugin is called in any project-X.

Comment: This indeed works when the build plugin is mentioned in the parent pom. However, when the build plugin is mentioned in project-x, it does not work. I notice that `build-helper-maven-plugin:1.10:add-resource` is done before the build plugin (which is good), but the `maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources)` is not (which is bad). The build plugin is indeed bound to the `generate-sources` phase (`@Mojo(name = "build-plugin", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.GENERATE_SOURCES)`). Is this a bug in Maven? Should I make another SO question for this?

Comment: @SteveKelio ***However, when the build plugin is mentioned in project-x, it does not work.*** I think that's another problem that need to be addressed in a new SO question. ***the maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) is not (which is bad).*** Try to declare the maven-resources-plugin between build helper plugin and the build plugin in the parent pom.

Comment: It works indeed when manually mentioning `maven-resources-plugin` in the pom and binding it to the `generate-sources` phase. However, now I doubt if this is an ideal solution, since now _**all**_ resource handling is done during the `generate-sources` phase. The point of the `generate-resources` and `process-resources` phase is now gone, if I am correct.

Comment: @SteveKelio You can create a property `build.plugin.config` that the build plugin use to find config.xml. The build plugin will be responsible for filtering the config file. See Maven Filter api.